# Diamond Back Ascent EX

Tags: vintage, diamondback

I just purchased this vintage Gem, serial number 87H2509, I am planning to give a complete restore, with the exception of paint, paint is chipped a little but I really love the old school decals that are still intact, they looks 80’s
Could the bike be an ‘87, also can I source replacement components to keep her as true as possible?

Comment: Did you locate the serial number inside the left rear dropouts?  If so, and based on the first two characters being numbers (and they do denote the year of manufacture), Diamondback frames with this serial number location and form are ones that were manufactured in Japan by a company called Koizumi.    If you Google "Diamondback serial number" you'll have lots of information to work with.

Comment: I found [this website](http://mombatbicycles.com/MOMBAT/BikeHistoryPages/Diamond_Back.html) which has a link to the 1987 Diamondback catalog. If you hit the catalog link in the website, a page shows up wherein the Ascent EX specs are listed.